# How to make the line of <hr> tag position right below the <h> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, let look these 2 pictures:

**1**-Ugly pic: where space between the line of `<hr>` and the `<h>` tag is too big.

[image]

**2**-Nice pic: where space between the line of `<hr>` and the `<h>` tag is kept minimum.

[image]

Can we achieve that in css?

Comment: What have you tried? How about making a jsfiddle page showing your attempt.

Comment: Sure you can achieve that with CSS.  I would go and look at the CSS of the page where you pulled the nice-pic (assuming that it's from a webpage) and see how they styled it...

Comment: i have no idea how to do simple cos H tag gave a big space beneath it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve putting `border-bottom` on `h1` tag.

```
<h1>Samsung Galaxy S5</h1>

h1{font-weight:normal;border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;}
```

I've made a example here which shows the difference if you used only `heading tags` and `headings tag` with `<hr>` tag. By default all heading tags `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6` have some `padding` and `margin` which is varies on every browser.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/movekaxa/1/edit)** to see the difference between using `margin and padding` or without `margin; padding`

Comment: wait, if i do h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
}  then the line is automatically inserted in every H tag. Can we do this only when we use Hr

Comment: if you don't want every <h> tag applied border then removed it. and apply this css for `<hr>` tag. `hr{border:1px solid #ef8913;margin:-9px; padding:0}` Now you have to play with margin a bit as per your desire result.

Comment: I think i can just use 
h1{font-weight:normal;border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;} since it is more natural than doing it in Hr

Comment: using negative margin instead of overriding the default margin or padding is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post any code I assume this is a general and not specific problem.

This can be achieved with CSS using `padding` or `margin` properties, depending on scenario.

By default the browsers add some style. Most browsers use `margin` for this space (since it is most appropriate in this scenario).

Here is an example of adjusting that margin to resemble the wikipedia screenshot:

http://jsfiddle.net/D5gmV/

```
h1{
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
}

h3{
    margin:10px 0;
}
hr{
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. I am using GWT & css is just a part of GWT, not sure that is main reason

Comment: GWT is a java framework that generates HTML + CSS + javascript components. You need to import your own CSS style that overrides the browsers default. This works as you can see in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly like Kheema already suggested it is better practice to use the border css property than the html hr element. The hr element is more about semantics now than presentation.